# java : annotations before method parameters

Tags: java, android, annotations

Can someone please provide more info on below Annotation example.

I know in this scenario it is used to restrict parameters value, but what this feature is called, and how can we create such methods. ?

```
            public boolean onNewMessage(@NonNull String message, @Subjects.Type String type) {
                LogItem item = LogItem.from(message, type);
                backups.add(item);
                return addItemToFiltered(item);
            }
```

Comment: There's no name to it. They are just annotations. What do you mean _how can we create such methods_? Write a method, annotate its parameters.

Answer (score -1):

In Java 8, there is a new annotation `@NonNull`

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_s_new_type

However, I don't know the source of your code, and I have not heard of `@Subjects.Type`.  So the annotations in your code may come from some lesser-known projects.

Note that anyone can create their own annotations:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Check if there is an `import` statement at the top of your file.  They can give you the full quantified package path of the annotations, and they may give you more clues.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know we can create our own Annotations, and Subjects is coming from RxJava. But it giving me indication that we can create  methods.. and  restrict its parameters to certain class or strings with Annotations.. And my question is how to create such methods.. @Notnull is fine, but what about others..

Comment: I doubt the method itself would do anything with the annotation.  If the annotations have any effects other than hinting the compiler and the human (the programmer), then they would be processed off-line (like compiler) and by a tool.  The following note may also be useful (from the annotation tutorial): "**Where Annotations Can Be Used**: 
Annotations can be applied to declarations: declarations of classes, fields, methods, and other program elements. When used on a declaration, each annotation often appears, by convention, on its own line."

Comment: Java 8 does not contain an annotation `@NonNull`.  However, Java 8 supports type annotations, which means that anyone can create a `@NonNull` annotation or any other annotation that they want.  This is explained by the blog that you quoted, which remarked that the [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) defines a [`@NonNull` annotation](https://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/NonNull.html).